# error "Sanitizer provider is not configured in the web.config file. "

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to use htmleditor from ajaxtoolkit. I have downloaded toolkit from [this link](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/100852)

**Ajax Control Toolkit .NET 3.5**

But getting an error as "**Sanitizer provider is not configured in the web.config file. If you are using the HtmlEditorExtender with a public website then please configure a Sanitizer provider. Otherwise, set the EnableSanitization property to false.**"

**.aspx**

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtBox1">
    </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox1" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="10"
        Text="Hello <b>world!</b>" />
```

I have searched many sites.. I get the below code as a solution to add in a web.config
But getting an error as "**Could not load type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider".** Also a line is coming under word **sanitizer**

```
<configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web">
            <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
        <sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="AntiXssSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider"></add>
            </providers>
        </sanitizer>
    </system.web>
```

**AjaxControltoolkit**

[image]

**Sanitizer provider folder**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change `sanitizer` section in web.config with this lines and try:

```
<sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
    </providers>
</sanitizer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update through the Nuget package manager..
so all the issue automatically resolve.

Install as below In Visual Studio Package Manager console:

1. PM > Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit
2. PM > Install-Package AntiXSS
3. PM > Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer
4. PM > Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack -Version 1.4.9

**Add New Section under:**

```
    <configuration>  
        <configSections>
        <section name="ajaxControlToolkit" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxControlToolkitConfigSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
</configSections>        
....
        ...

    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.0" newVersion="1.4.9.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
        <ajaxControlToolkit htmlSanitizer="AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer.DefaultHtmlSanitizer, AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer" />
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the files from AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET40.zip into bin folder.

This is the configs you need in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
...
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </sectionGroup>

....

  <system.web>
    <sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </sanitizer>
```

And in your aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="CommunitySafeApp.Start.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" />
<asp:TextBox
        ID="txtComments"
        TextMode="MultiLine"
        Columns="60"
        Rows="8"
        runat="server" />

<asp:HtmlEditorExtender
        TargetControlID="txtComments"
        runat="server" />

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```